# How to avoid requiring any native libraries for compression in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compression

We are doing a POC on a variety of server machines/architectures. We do not have the ability to rebuild native compression libraries for all of them.

Which codec is software only?  The default snappy is giving the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 lz4
```

Is software only. That is working.

The way to configure: in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`:

```
 spark.io.compression.codec lz4
```